# JavaParser and SymbolSolver for Eclipse Scout

Tags: java, eclipse, javaparser, eclipse-scout, javasymbolsolver

I want to analyze dependencies among classes which I have started using [JavaParser](https://github.com/javaparser/javaparser) and it's SymbolResolver for. But it keeps failing when resolving several of the method references on a sample project from [Eclipse Scout](https://www.eclipse.org/scout/). Scout uses it's own [BEAN manager](https://eclipsescout.github.io/6.0/technical-guide.html#sec-bean.manager) where it loads java classes at jvm startup into a list which makes it more flexible to load and unload classes at runtime. But Eclipse IDE is able to resolve the dependencies *somehow*. Here is my working example which I use for parsing the Eclipse Scout project:

```java
    private static String getFullyQualifiedName(MethodCallExpr exp) {
        String result = "";
        try {
            result = exp.getName() + " --> " + exp.resolve().getQualifiedSignature();
        } catch (RuntimeException e) {
            result = "!unable to resolve! " + exp.getName();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static void runAnalysis(String sourceFolder) {
        final ProjectRoot projectRoot = new SymbolSolverCollectionStrategy().collect(new File(sourceFolder).toPath());
        projectRoot.getSourceRoots().forEach(sourceRoot -> sourceRoot.tryToParseParallelized()
            .forEach(parsedSource -> parsedSource.getResult().get().findAll(MethodCallExpr.class)
                .forEach(exp -> System.out.println(parsedSource.getResult().get().getPackageDeclaration().get().getNameAsString()
                    + "." + parsedSource.getResult().get().getStorage().get().getFileName()
                    + " (" + exp.getBegin().get().line + ") "
                    + getFullyQualifiedName(exp)))));
    }
```

I add all maven dependency JAR's to the source root folder as well as all the source code and I am just using a plain helloworld example from Scout. To me it seems quite random why and when it works vs. when it fails to resolve the MethodCallEx. Java Symbol Solver is even able to resolve some of the BEAN.get() dependencies which is nice.

A successful output looks like this:

```
scout.ui.html.UiServletFilter.java (66) destroy --> org.eclipse.scout.rt.server.commons.authentication.DevelopmentAccessController.destroy()
```

And a failed output like that:

```
scout.server.helloworld.HelloWorldService.java (15) !unable to resolve! getUserId
```

But Eclipse IDE is able to resolve all classes and method calls.

Comment: I have now added my whole local maven repository `C:\Users\jofroe\.m2` to the source path of the sample project and it is able to resolve many additional dependencies, even some with BEAN access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your analysis happen at runtime or in the IDE based on the source-code? The former would be a question about the Scout *runtime* and the BeanManager which is used when BEANS is called, the latter is a question about the Scout *SDK*, which you can download [here](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/): Eclipse IDE for Scout Developers.

I assume you want to analyze the source-code. When you download the Eclipse package mentioned above, you get the Eclipse IDE with additional plugins for Eclipse Scout. These plugins use tools provided by the Eclipse platform to analyze Scout classes. So I'd suggest you take a look at the [Eclipse Scout SDK source-code](https://git.eclipse.org/c/scout/org.eclipse.scout.sdk.git/tree/?h=releases/6.0.x) and use the same tools for your analysis. Make sure you choose the release branch that matches the version of your Scout project.

Comment: Salü Andre! It was an issue with JavaParser's SymbolSolver, the EclipseScout is fine. I have already switched to Eclipse's AST parser which works fine and is able to resolve all dependencies (i.e. method calls). I have just forgotten about this question I posted.. Grüessli Josua